# Creating a new field based on ranges in a field using Field Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a field (`Tot_Score`) that has scores from 2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I would like to create 4 classes out of these scores whereby the classes will be created in another field (`Vul_Class`) so 1st class = 2 and 3, 2nd Class = 4 and 5, 3rd Class = 6 and 7, 4th Class = 8.

What is the script I would need in the QGIS Field Calculator to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
CASE
  WHEN  "Tot_Score" = 2 OR "Tot_Score" = 3 THEN 1
  WHEN  "Tot_Score" = 4 OR "Tot_Score" = 5 THEN 2
  WHEN  "Tot_Score" = 6 OR "Tot_Score" = 7 THEN 3
  WHEN  "Tot_Score" = 8 THEN 4
END
```